# Learning curves for RandomForest

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, random-forest

I'm using a `RandomForestClassifier` for a binary classification problem.
I plotted the following learning curve. Can I say that more training data would benefit this model?
image:
[Learning curve for RandomForest Classifier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHpSq.png)

Answer (score 0):

From the training curve, it is clear accuracy will not improve by adding more instances.